# Tree<String> Data Structure in C#

Tags: c#, tree

Good morning,

Is there any good, efficient and good-performance n-ary tree data structure implementation for C#? I don't need any flexibility regarding the type of the nodes, since I only need to store strings. However, I would like fast lookup time. Also, I need to label "edges" of the tree with (short) integers, but these labels can well be stored at each node.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are about a gazillion and 1 ways to implement trees. Lookup at best is O(log N).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
public class CustomTreeNode
{
    public String Label { get; set; }
    public List<CustomTreeNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Also, you can always try [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode%28VS.71%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but there's a pretty good example here:

[Tree example](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XElement to build a tree. This is not exactly what you are looking for, but still it can be useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx